# Adding ethics as an alias for philosophy?

Tags: feature-request, alias

Ethics is a pretty broad field. In fact, there are ethics tags in IPS, Workplace, Academia, and, of course, philosophy.

Considering that philosophy is usually the department where ethics is taught and researched actively as a field, a person who tries to figure out where to post a question on ethics would normally be in good hands when going to philosophy.SE.

A person who has a very specific, field related problem, will look for the specific sites anyway.

So I've been told that the question occurred why ethics.stackexchange.com is not an alias of philosophy.stackexchange.com and that an additional the idea was philosophy as a hit if "ethics" is typed into the hamburger menu.

What does the community think? As I am a moderator on philosophy, I do not want to appear as if I think the other sites should not address ethics. They surely have to and the ethics of e.g. workspace and academia ethics are quite peculiar at times and need a specialist to answer. I am basically asking this on behalf of a user who genuinely had this question and raised it in chat.

Comment: Are there a lot of users struggling to find the appropriate place to ask their ethics questions?

Comment: @Servy Hard to tell. 100% of the observable population finds it. And the ones who don't you never hear from.

Comment: @nwp We see plenty of people posting because they're unsure of where to ask their question and don't know where they should be posting, or who are posting questions that need to get migrated/re-posted because there's a better place.  Sure you don't get information from *every* person that had trouble finding the right site, but you certainly get a relevant portion.  For other sites that really are struggling to be found by people with questions that would be appropriate there we see plenty of that signal, and can use that to make adjustments.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as "alias" in Stack Exchange. The site official name is the sub domain, the only exceptions are sites which changed their name, so the old name still exists as the sub domain. As for communities list, the site description is used, so in theory "ethics" can be added to that description.

Comment: The philosophy site needs to decide for themselves whether they even want this in the first place. What MSE users think is sort of irrelevant.

Comment: @Sha there are site aliases. See https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=160&filter=!6P.EhvnWknhjL&run=true  ...e.g. Unix & Linux has both http://unix.stackexchange.com/ and http://linux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Cai oh, good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It may not officially be an alias, but you can achieve what you want by changing the little bit of text for the site.

Here I am "searching" the sites for "enthusiast". Even though there is no enthusiast.stackexchange.com, I get plenty of hits:

[image]

The text for Philosophy right now is

[image]

> For those interested in the study of the fundamental nature of knowledge, reality, and existence

Persuade them (presumably on their meta) to include the word ethics in this text, and **Mission Accomplished**.